# git not recognizing local repository path in command

Tags: git

I am trying to pull a `git tag` from a local repository in another directory. That is I am executing the git command from an external directory. In the below the `--git-dir=/path/to/git` does have the `.git` in it and is where I submit new files to, but the command doesn't recognize it. Reading it seems `git -C` might be a better option, but I don't see that as an option in help. Thank you :).

```
git --version

1.8.3.1

git --git-dir=/path/to/git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1))

fatal: no git repository in /path/to/git
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the .git directory in your checkout. You also need `--git-dir` in your sub command.

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/git/.git describe --tags $(git --git-dir=/path/to/git/.git rev-list --tags --max-count=1))
```

Comment: Thank you very much :)